# How to stop CACHE instance from Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, intersystems-cache

I want to restart CACHE(database that I am using) Instance from shell script. What I did is created a function in the shell script named `restart_cache`.

```
restart_cache()
{
 ccontrol stop instancename restart
}
```

This command is running but the control goes to cache and while stopping cache it gets stuck waiting for an answer here:

```
Do you want to broadcast a message to anyone? No =>
```

How can I pass the value here through shell script

Comment: Piping your command after echo|<cachestopcommand> does not work?

Comment: I don't know that database, but it's possible ccontrol has an option not to ask. Try running ccontrol with -h, -?, --help or --nosuchoption to see if it spews out a help message. *If all fails, read the instructions*. :-)

Comment: It is a database from Intersystem. You can search for Intersystem cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accept all of the defaults, you can use

```
ccontrol stop instancename restart quietly
```

Comment: But if i want to perform some command on cache from shell script then what should i do? 
Should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: It is not difficult, but post it as a separate question.

Comment: I had posted it, can you check it out

Comment: How can I perform some commands on Intersystem cache from shellscript?